# python 3.x : How to write/append text to a existing file as per user input in new line?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write or append data as per user input from a terminal to a file which has some data. My code as mentioned below, it is allowing me to add/append but not as new line. I have tried to solve it but not able to figure out, what am I doing wrong?

```
f = open("test1.txt","a+");
print ("Name of the file:",f.name);
#rdl = f.readline();
#print ("This is my readline : %s" % rdl);
#f.seek(0,2);
usrtext = input("Enter your text which you want to add : " + "\n");
f.seek(0,2);
f.write(usrtext);
f.seek(0,0);
rlds = f.readlines();
print ("This is my readlines : %s\n" % rlds);
#Close opened file

f.close();
```

**Expected output :**

```
This is my new line 1 
This is my append/write line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just commented `f.seek(0,2)` in this code and got the expected output in the file.

Working code is as below :

```
f = open("test1.txt","a+");
print ("Name of the file:",f.name);
#f.close();
#rdl = f.readline();
#print ("This is my readline : %s" % rdl);
#f.seek(0,2);
usrtext = input("Enter your text which you want to add : " + "\n");
**#f.seek(0,2);**
f.write("\n" + usrtext);
f.seek(0,0);
rlds = f.readlines();
print ("This is my readlines : %s\n" % rlds);
#Close opened file

f.close();
```